# Error al comparar if : "java: bad operand types for binary operator"

Tags: java, array, if

Tengo un pequeño problema en el que trato de compara un array con una opcion int en un IF introducida por el usuario, me sale un error. No programo todo en el Main y utilizo varias clases y me comunico entre ellas.

Me gustaria hacer que el ususario seleccione el chiste que quiere y darle una puntuacion sobre 5 y asi poder guaradarlo en la array del chiste seleccionado.

El error:

> java: bad operand types for binary operator '==' first type: 
>   com.company.Model.Chiste second type: int

Este es el codig de la clase ManagerChiste

```
public class ManagerChistes {
public Chiste[] chistes = new Chiste[10];

public void valorarChiste(int opcion, int valor) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chistes.length; i++) {
        if (chistes[i] == (opcion - 1)) { -----> Error
            chistes[i].valor = valor;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo de la clase PantallaValorarChiste

```
public class PantallaValorarChiste {
public void iniciar(ManagerUsuarios managerUsuarios, ManagerChistes managerChistes) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    System.out.println("Chistometro :: Valorar Chiste");
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < managerChistes.chistes.length; i++) {
        if (managerChistes.chistes[i] != null){
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Numero chiste:" + (i+1));
            System.out.println("Titulo:     |\t" + managerChistes.chistes[i].titulo);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }

    boolean esValido = false;

    while(!esValido) {
        System.out.println("1) Valorar chiste");
        System.out.println("2) Volver a ver chistes");
        System.out.println("3) Volver");
        System.out.println("4) Log out");
        System.out.println("5) Salir");
        String option = scanner.nextLine();

        if ("1".equals(option)) {
            System.out.println("¿Que chiste quieres valorar? Selecciona un nuemro.");
            int opcion = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Que valoracion le quieres dar? (Sobre 5)");
            int valor = scanner.nextInt();

            managerChistes.valorarChiste(opcion, valor);

            System.out.println("Valoracion añadida");
            PantallaMenuApp pantallaMenuApp = new PantallaMenuApp();
            pantallaMenuApp.mostrar(managerUsuarios, managerChistes);
        } else if ("2".equals(option)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < managerChistes.chistes.length; i++) {
                if (managerChistes.chistes[i] != null){
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Numero chiste:" + (i+1));
                    System.out.println("Titulo:     |\t" + managerChistes.chistes[i].titulo);
                    System.out.println("Cuerpo:     |\t" + managerChistes.chistes[i].cuerpo);
                    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
                }
            }
            esValido = false;
        } else if ("3".equals(option)) {
            PantallaMenuApp pantallaMenuApp = new PantallaMenuApp();
            pantallaMenuApp.mostrar(managerUsuarios, managerChistes);
            esValido = true;
        } else if ("4".equals(option)) {
            PantallaInicio pantallaInicio = new PantallaInicio();
            pantallaInicio.iniciar(managerUsuarios, managerChistes);
            esValido = true;
        } else if ("4".equals(option)) {
            System.out.println("Hasta luego");
            esValido = true;
        } else{
            System.out.println("Error opcion no valida");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            esValido = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error es que estas realizando una comparación de un objeto `Chiste` con un entero, lo cual es incorrecto.

```
   if (chistes[i] == (opcion - 1)) { -----> Error
```

El mensaje dice algo como:

> java: tipos de operandos incorrectos para el operador binario "=="
>   primer tipo: com.company.Model.Chiste segundo tipo: int

Debes obtener el "valor" del objeto `Chiste` y realizar la comparación entre valores de tipo entero:

```
 if (chistes[i].valor == (opcion - 1)) {
```